# Typescript type binding issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component in Typescript which uses `react-jss` and `classes` object for styles. I'm receiving the following error: `Binding element 'classes' implicitly has an 'any' type.`, and can't figure out how to fix it.

**App.tsx**

```
import CaseStudyCard from './components/CaseStudyCard'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CaseStudyCard 
        title="Preparing organizations for the future"
        text="This is the body of the card and should wrap continuously" 
        industry="Healthcare" 
        location="Nowheresville" 
        image="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/600x400"  
        date="March 22nd 2021"
        link="https://www.google.com"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**CaseStudyCard.tsx**

```
import WithStyles, {createUseStyles } from 'react-jss';

const useStyles = createUseStyles({
    card: {
        width: 280,
        display: 'block',
        margin: '60px auto',
        boxShadow: '0px 0px 2px 0px #000',
        transition: '.25s',
        '&:hover': {
          boxShadow: '0px 0px 4px 0px #000',
          transform: 'translateY(5px)'
        }
      },
      cardHeader: {
        height: 150,
        padding: 15,
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        color: '#fff',
        '& h4':{
            textTransform: 'uppercase',
            margin: 0,
        }
      },
      cardBody: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
      },
      date: {
        fontSize: 11,
        fontWeight: 600,
        color: 'grey',
      },
      bodyContent: {
        paddingBottom: 40,
        fontSize: 13,
        lineHeight: 1.8,
      },
      buttonPrimary: {
        border: '1px solid #000',
        padding: 10,
        fontFamily: 'inherit',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        color: '#000',
        fontSize: 15,
        transition: '.25s',
        margin: '0 0 20px',
        borderRadius: 3,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        bottom: 20,
        position: 'relative',
        textDecoration: 'none'
      },
      designerLink: {
        color: '#fff',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fonSize: 12,
        textDecoration: 'none',
        display: 'block',
      }
    });

    type ClassesType = {
      buttonPrimary?: string,
      bodyContent: string,
      cardHeader: string,
      cardBody: string,
      date: string
    }


    interface CardHeaderType extends WithStyles(classes) {
      classes?: ClassesType,
      image: string;
     }
    const CardHeader = ({classes, image}: CardHeaderType) => {
          const style = { 
              backgroundImage: `url(${image})`,
          };
          return (
            <header style={style} className={classes.cardHeader}>
              <h4>News</h4>
            </header>
          )
      }

      interface ButtonType {
        classes?: ClassesType,
        link: string
      }
      const Button = ({classes, link}: ButtonType) => (
            <a href={link} className={classes.buttonPrimary}>
              Find out more
            </a>   
      )
      
      interface CardBodyType {
        classes?: ClassesType,
        date: Date,
        title: string,
        text: string,
        link: string
      }
      const CardBody = ({classes, date, title, text, link}: CardBodyType) => {
          return classes && Object.keys(classes).length > 0 ? (
            <div className={classes.cardBody}>
              <p className={classes.date}>{date}</p>
              <h2>{title}</h2>
              <p className={classes.bodyContent}>{text}</p>
              <Button classes={classes} link={link}/>
            </div>) : null
      }
      
     interface CaseStudyCardProps {
       image: string,
       classes?: ClassesType,
       title: string,
       date: string,
       location: string,
       industry: string,
       link: string,
       text: string
     } 
      export default function CaseStudyCard (props: CaseStudyCardProps) {
        console.log(props)
        const classes = useStyles()
        return (
            <div className={classes.card}>
              <CardHeader classes={props.classes} image={props.image}/>
              <CardBody 
                classes={props.classes} 
                title={props.title} 
                date={props.date}
                location={props.location}
                industry={props.industry}
                link={props.link}
                text={props.text}
              />
            </div>
          )
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its most likely because you haven't defined types on this line:

```
const CardHeader = ({classes, image})
```

You probably have typescript configured to not allow implicit any typing.

You can fix it by defining types for this parameter something like this:

```
interface IParameterType {
 classes: ClassesType;
 image: ImageType;
}
...
const CardHeader = ({classes, image}: IParameterType)
```

And probably other lines also, but you can use this as an example to fix it.

There are others with implicit any typing as well, this for example:

```
  const Button = ({classes, link}) => (
```

same case as the first one.

**UPDATE**

You would also have to create the types `ImageType` and `ClassesType` I placed it just as an example.

**UPDATE 2**

To create the types like this, for example for the `classes` parameter:

```
type ClassesType = {
 cardHeader: string;
 date: Date;
 buttonPrimary?: string;
}
```

You use the `?` in front of the property name to make it so that it can be undefined.

You can also make properties nullable like this:

```
type ClassesType = {
 cardHeader: string | null;
 date: Date;
 buttonPrimary?: string;
}
```

The `cardHeader: string | null` means that the property `cardHeader` can be a string **or** null.

The `buttonPrimary?: string;` means that the property `buttonPrimary` can be a **string** or **null** or **undefined**.

You can read more about it here:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

and learn more about types and interfaces on typescript with this playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/types-vs-interfaces

Comment: I tried implementing your updates, but I get the error `Cannot find name 'ClassesType'`

Comment: this type you have to create also

Comment: I updated the answer: you would also need to create (or use existing) types for the objects. The types of classes and image probably already exist inside the library. If they don't you also have to define them

Comment: How do you create types for the objects? Sorry, I'm new to TypeScript.

Comment: I edited the post with an update with an example and sources to playground and docs

Comment: You can also disable this check inside tsconfig.json. Setting the property noImplicitAny. There are tons of examples online on how to do it if you wish to

Comment: I set `"noImplicitAny": false,`, which disabled the error, but now I get `Property 'location' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { classes: any; date: any; title: any; text: any; link: any; }'`

Comment: you need to add the property `location` to the type you are creating. like `location: any`

Comment: you will also need to add the property `industry` also

Comment: I've made the recommended updates (and updated code in the question above), but receiving this error which I can't figure out: `Type 'object | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ClassesType'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ClassesType'`

Comment: The most up to date code is in the original question above.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5IkgKuaBeKBvAWACgooB6MqAJQgFsB7AN2mAAsBLJALigGNEUaHngC+AbmKkARgFdgwegDsACgCd2tBKpAB+HkmDrFAcwkkoU+gBMQMJcAiLg+w+xNnSvLVYASEBFYQqi5GppJ83gBC1iAhbmHmVggOcSYANMQixMQU1HRMLBzcOZSgkFAAkprGEJjluIREuaRQGgg1qQm5WUTEbg6qAGYIvNAw3n4BQXXQjZ4CqNywC2gzHq3VEJ1i5JRV7bVYO7m8rAgmhZxQClAGoZnZRP1Bw6OwyBAAysAyNuOqVjU9DASHw4TaHVurnS4X4yEWPHg8NWR12sDOF2uRR4cMESD0UHoUgAVhBeMAMuZgOxgHAtlDQpTSEkUgz4kyoHB6F5qUpOhy3FYZHdYmyYeY4G4ANb88IOAAezjFxkyUGIQA

Comment: take a look at these fixes, the changes are commented

Comment: I don't see any comments.

Comment: check the link I sent on the comment above

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5IkgKuaBeKBvAWACgooB6MqAJQgFsB7AN2mAAsBLJALigGNEUaHngC+AbmKkARgFdgwegDsACgCd2tBKpAB+HkmDrFAcwkkoU+gBMQMJcAiLg+w+xNnSvLVYASEBFYQqi5GppJ83gBC1iAhbmHmVggOcSYANMQixMQU1HRMLBzcOZSgkFAAkprGEJjluIREuaRQGgg1qQm5WUTEbg6qAGYIvNAw3n4BQXXQjZ4CqNywC2gzHq3VEJ1i5JRV7bVYO7m8rAgmhZxQClAGoZnZRP1Bw6OwyBAAysAyNuOqVjU9DASHw4TaHVurnS4X4yEWPHg8NWR12sDOF2uRR4cMESD0UHoUgAVhBeMAMuZgOxgHAtlDQpTSEkUgz4kyoHB6F5qUpOhy3FYZHdYmyYeY4G4ANb88IOAAezjFxkyUGIQA

Comment: Ah, the link didn't show up previously. Updated the Interfaces and Types, but getting `Property 'classes' is missing in type '{ title: string; text: string; industry: string; location: string; image: string; date: string; link: string; }' but required in type 'CaseStudyCardProps'`. Updated code above to reflect your updates.

Comment: inside `CaseStudyCardProps` change `classes: ClassesType` to `classes?: ClassesType`

Comment: I'd added that right after, but getting `Type 'ClassesType | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ClassesType'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ClassesType'`

Comment: you have to change all `classes: ClassesType` to `classes?: ClassesType`

Comment: Updated all where necessary, and now getting `Object is possibly 'undefined'` for the `classes.cardHeader` in `<header style={style} className={classes.cardHeader}>`. Each of these Typescript updates is exposing some interesting issues. Any idea what would cause this? Thanks!

Comment: these are all just errors from inconsistency on typing. this one for example, the problem is that you are defining a `className` that possibly can be `undefined` so imagine if this className is transpiled to a `class` property on html, it would cause a lot of trouble.

Comment: So typescript is telling you that this ClassType cannot be `undefined` so its telling you to remove all the `?` in front of classes property. Because that would cause an inconsistency

Comment: But that class exists in the styles object, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: which class? the class from the classes property?

Comment: The class on `className={classes.cardHeader}`. That `cardHeader` class has a style.

Comment: but the `className={classes.cardHeader}` property comes from the props inside `CaseStudyCard ` function. Which has the type `CaseStudyCardProps`, so if the property `classes` inside CaseStudyCardProps has the `?` in front of it it can possibly be undefined. So this generates the error

Comment: So this is where I'm confused on how to avoid this error. How can I tell it that the prop will always have that class?

Comment: Well I just checked the react-jss documentation: https://cssinjs.org/react-jss/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.16#usage-with-typescript There are types already defined for these props apparently

Comment: Hmm, not sure I understand the implementation here. Mind checking (updated the code in the question with the suggested implementation from the link you sent.